# HDInsight: Can't run a hive query from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-hdinsight

I spun up my 1st HDInsight cluster.  Everything is running green.

[image]

I want to run a simple Hive query.  The problem is that the documentation talks about a Hive editor window, which I do not see (https://chickenhadoop.azurehdinsight.net/#/main/services/HIVE/editor)

I went over to Visual Studio to see if I could run the query from there. 
[image]

When I navigate to the cluster, I get the following error:
[image]

Can anyone help me run a hive query on HDInsight?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'do not see'? Do you not see the menu option in ambari toolbar? do you get an error?

Comment: The is no munu option for a Hive Editor.

Comment: Just making sure we are on the same page, this menu doesn't show?: https://acom.azurecomcdn.net/80C57D/cdn/mediahandler/docarticles/dpsmedia-prod/azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-hive-ambari-view/20160913101040/selecthiveview.png

Comment: OK,.  I see that there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting our solution from comments discussion for future reference:

You can access the hive view from the ambari toolbar:

[image: ambari toolbar hive view]

more details here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-hive-ambari-view/